# Retroactively Strip MS Word Formatting

Tags: asp-classic, ms-word

I have an ASP website in which hundreds of users submitted essay question answers that were pasted in from MS Word.  Once pasted into the editor, they did not realize that the formatting was not stripped and went ahead and submitted. The system is running on MS SQL Server.  Is there any way for me NOT to have to go back to all of these users and strip the unreadable characters/formatting myself?

Comment: I am not sure what you have, but you may be able to consider regex or writing out to Word and then Save As text.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions to remove tags like div, font, style, ... before displaying the content.

for example to remove all font tags:

```
<font[^><]*>|<.font[^><]*>
```